# Nexstar Dual Bay Hard Drive Dock without format?

Tags: hard-drive-recovery

My computer was replaced by dell. They also sent me hard drives out of the laptop. I did not want to wait for a computer store to recover my data so I bought Nexstar Dual Bay Hard Drive Dock. How can I get the data off with this? Right away it wants to format. Any way around this?

Also, when I bring up the hard drive, format message right away.

Comment: If it wants to format the drive there is no file system there is a chance the recovery of the files will not be possible what recovery software have you tried?

Comment: I haven't tried any. What do you recommend?

Comment: There are plenty of questions with suggestions product recommendations are not on topic here at Superuser.

Comment: first things first. what is the SMART health status of the disk in question? I use speedfan to read smart health statistics in Windows.